# WPF make combobox binding twoways

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I have a combo box that is editable, and i have a button that is enable when SelectedReplacement that binds to the combobox is not null and disable when it is. When it's null, i would input some random text to make the button enable, the problem is it wouldn't become enable when there I input text. making the Mode TwoWay doesn't help. i assumed setting the propertychangedevent would bind the new text to SelectedReplacement, but Im wrong, so any help is appreciated.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedError.Suggestions}"
                      Text="{m:Binding Path=SelectedError.SelectedReplacement, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

i also tried to get the propertychanged

```
    private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(SpellcheckViewModel sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(sender.SelectedError.SelectedReplacement))
        {
            _correctCommand?.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to write a demo project to meet your requirement.

Mainly, the enable state is controlled by another boolean property `IsButtonEnabled` in the view model, the value for that property is controlled by `InputText` property which is controlled by the text you input in the ComboBox control.

Here is the UI:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <ComboBox
        x:Name="cmb"
        IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
        TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cmb_TextChanged"
        TextSearch.TextPath="Name">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="hiddenTextBox"
        Text="{Binding InputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button
        x:Name="btn"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        Content="Show message"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the main logic in the view model:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Item> AllItems
    {
        get { return _allItems; }
        set { _allItems = value; this.RaisePropertyChanged("AllItems"); }
    }

    public bool IsButtonEnabled
    {
        get { return _isButtonEnabled; }
        set { _isButtonEnabled = value; this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When InputValue changed, change the enable state of the button based on the current conditions
    /// </summary>
    public string InputText
    {
        get { return _inputText; }
        set
        {
            _inputText = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("InputText");

            // You can control the enable state of the button easily
            if (AllItems.Any(item => item.Name == value))
            {
                // SelectedItem is not null
                IsButtonEnabled = true;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                // SelectedItem is null
                IsButtonEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsButtonEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is the project: [ComboBoxDemo](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvTsWSNn_H8alZlAYwK5-21sAMWeTw)